# Java Project to Groovy - Libraries don't work

Tags: java, groovy, jar

I wrote a program in java and now I want to run it using groovy. I did this as an exercise, so don't question why I haven't programmed in groovy in the first place. ;)

I used many libraries in java, so I copied them to the `%GROOVY_HOME%\lib` directory. After I did this, I wasn't able to run groovyConsole.exe anymore, so ran groovyConsole.bat (using cmd) to get the error, which is following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.4.11\bin>groovyConsole.bat
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:109)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:131)
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:116)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.doParse(XmlSettingsParser.java:160)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.parse(XmlSettingsParser.java:150)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.load(IvySettings.java:417)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings$load.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.<init>(GrapeIvy.groovy:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at groovy.grape.Grape.getInstance(Grape.java:121)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1850)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3758)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
        at groovy.ui.ConsoleIvyPlugin.addListener(ConsoleIvyPlugin.groovy:44)
        at groovy.ui.ConsoleIvyPlugin$addListener.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at groovy.ui.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:242)
        at groovy.ui.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:224)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
        at groovy.ui.Console.main(Console.groovy:209)
        ... 6 more
```

The libs I used worked fine in eclipse using java. What can I do?

Additional question:

I found a way to use libraries by loading files. Is there a way to load intire directories with jar files?

```
this.getClass().classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new File("file.jar").toURL())
```

Comment: Don't copy things to %Groovy_Home%/lib, set them up as proper dependencies on the classpath, or build with a shadow/shade plugin to generate a fat jar

Comment: You shouldn't be copying libraries under `GROOVY_HOME/lib`. Instead use classpath to include your libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You should not add your script dependencies to `%GROOVY_HOME%/lib`.

You should instead change your script to declare the dependencies it needs.

One way is to do as you found with the adding JAR URLs to a class loader. If you want to add a directory, list the directory and iterate over the JAR files, something like `new File('path/to/dir').eachFileMatch('*.jar') { ...addURL(it.toURI().toURL()) }`.

Btw. as you can see in my example, you should never use `File.toURL()`, this is deprecated since a long time. Always do `File.toURI().toURL()` instead.

Besides all this, there is a better way to depend on libraries in Groovy scripts, which is Grape. You can read more about it at http://groovy-lang.org/grape.html. Basically you just declare your dependencies with annotations and they are automatically downloaded from a Maven repository and added to the classpath of your script, including any transitive dependencies.